# Excel: Auto populate cell in incremental sequence till a given value

Tags: excel, vba

So I select an integer value from a dropdown, e.g 5. I want to populate the sequence 1,2,3,4,5 from cells C1:C5 automatically. So if I change the value from dropdown to 2, only cells C1 C2 should be populated with values 1 and 2

Here's the VBA function I wrote:

```
Function POPULATE_VALUE(GIVEN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE)
   If GIVEN_VALUE <= MAX_VALUE Then
        POPULATE_VALUE = GIVEN_VALUE
    Else
        POPULATE_VALUE = ""
   End If
End Function
```

Assuming cell B3 contains my dropdown selected value, I use it as:

For cell C1: `=POPULATE_VALUE(1,B3)`, C2: `=POPULATE_VALUE(2,B3)`

Is there a better way to do this? I found the `SEQUENCE` function but it is only available in Office 365 for now.

Comment: Have you considered using a pure VBA subroutine, instead of VBA Function + formula?

Comment: No I haven't, can you please tell me how can I go about that. I am not that familiar with advanced excel concepts...

Comment: Sure, i'll write a small subroutine as an example, but you'll need some trigger to make it work (like a button click, or selection change on dropdown etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below formula. Put the formula to `C3` cell then drag and down till you need.

```
=IF(ROW($A1)>$B$3,"",ROW($A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Are you assuming columns A1:A5 to be empty here?

Comment: No. It don't care empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subroutine below.

```
Sub fill_numbers()
    ''clearing column C
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).ClearContents
    
    max_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
    For i = 1 To max_value
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value = i
    Next i

End Sub
```

It just loops from 1 to the value of the dropdown and keeps filling the numbers in column C.

You can set the trigger to change everytime there is a change in the value of the cell that has the dropdown.